# Bash: info with systemctl

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

With `systemctl status name.service | grep Active` I get this info:

```
Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-05-14 21:44:09 CEST; 5s ago
```

How can I get the same info but without: "Active: "?

Comment: What do you want this information *for*? As noted in the man page, `systemctl status` is intended to be human-readable: if you're going to start parsing/scripting it, you would likely be better off using `systemctl show` e.g. `systemctl show ssh.service --property=ActiveState,SubState,ExecMainStartTimestamp`

Comment: ok, I read the properties but your string will get `ExecMainStartTimestamp=Mon 2018-05-14 22:11:37 CEST
ActiveState=active
SubState=running` on 3 lines

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```bsh
grep -oP 'Active: \K.*'
```

to print the line without “Active: ”:

```bsh
$ systemctl status ssh.service | grep Active       
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-03-31 14:15:07 CEST; 1 months 13 days ago
$ systemctl status ssh.service | grep -oP 'Active: \K.*'
active (running) since Sat 2018-03-31 14:15:07 CEST; 1 months 13 days ago
```

- `-o` tells `grep` to print only the matched parts of a matching line
- `-P` enables Perl-compatible  regular  expressions  (PCRE), that’s needed to use `\K`, which keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.